# Running concurrent database queries in PHP per session?

Tags: php, ajax, oracle

I appear to be having some difficulties with handling running multiple database calls, especially in regards to large datasets being returned. **It appears that PHP only lets you have one database call running at a time, per session.** This normally isn't an issue, as the database calls tend to be so small it doesn't lock anything up, but the large ones cause this waiting issue.

I discovered this issue when I fixed an unrelated issue, and discovered that if you click a button to query the database via an AJAX call, then try to refresh the website, it won't start loading the website until that database call is done, as the page does have an internal function to make a database call. Conversely, if I were to start the database query, then load up a pure html webpage stating "Hello World", it loads instantly. **Based on this, Apache isn't having an issue serving, it's something to do with database connections.**

To point, I've isolated code that's possibly relevant, as I can't figure out why I'm only able to have one active call at a time. **In short, is there a way to have multiple database calls running per user at a time, or will a user have to wait?**

db_connect.php:

```
<?php
  $user = 'TEST';
  include_once 'config.php'; //Intialize constants for the connection
  $conn = oci_connect(USER, PASSWORD, '//'.HOST.':1630/'.DATABASE);
  oci_set_client_identifier($conn, $user); //Identify who's making these calls.
?>
```

events.php: (if I refresh this after clicking the ajax button to do the same fetch, it won't load until that AJAX call is finished. Doesn't matter if I have code to abort the call, the database is still running that database query.)

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include 'db_connect.php';
  include 'database/event_defs.php'; 
?>
<html>
  <!-- boilerplate nonsense -->
  <body>
  <table>
  <?php
    $dataset = get_event_list($conn, $_SESSION['username']); //Returns 1000 records, could take a while to fully retrieve it. 
    foreach($dataset as $key => $val) {
      //Make multiple rows happen here.
    }
  ?>
  </table>
  <button onclick="do_ajax_call('get_event_list');">Make DB Call</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

database/event_defs.php: (Probably the most relevant part).

```
<?php
  function get_event_list($conn, $user) {
    $l_result = array();
    $sql = 'BEGIN ...(:c_usr, :c_rslt); END'; //name is irrelevant.
    if($stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql)) {
      $l_results = oci_new_cursor($conn);
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':c_usr',$user);
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':c_rslt',$lresults,-1,OCI_B_CURSOR);
      if(oci_execute($conn)) {
        oci_execute($l_results); //Problem line, seems to stall out here for a while and won't let the user query again until this call finishes.
        while($r = oci_fetch_array($l_results, OCI_ASSOC) {
          $l_result[] = $r;
        }
      } else {
        return 'bad statement';
      }
    } else {
      return 'unable to connect';
    }

    return $l_result;
  }
?>
```

Version information:

PHP 5.4.45
Oracle 11g
Apache 2.2.15

Comment: The concurrent AJAX request issue is not caused by the database. You are experiencing session lock-up.

Comment: Try `session_write_close(); get_event_list($myConn, 'Orpheus');`. This will work only if you don't need to modify the session after calling `get_event_list($myConn, 'Orpheus');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MonkeyZeus monkey has already pointed out in the comments to your question, the second request is most likely only blocked by the session mechanism.
Since it looks like you don't need anything but the username from the session, just grab that value and finish the session mechanism.

```
<?php
session_start();
// check $_SESSION['username'] here if necessary
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
// no need to keep the session mecahnism "alive"
session_abort(); // and since nothing has been written to _SESSION, abort() should do.

require 'db_connect.php';
require 'database/event_defs.php'; 
?>
<html>
  <!-- boilerplate nonsense -->
  <body>
  <table>
  <?php
    $dataset = get_event_list($conn, $username); //Returns 1000 records, could take a while to fully retrieve it. 
    foreach($dataset as $key => $val) {
      //Make multiple rows happen here.
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: `session_abort()` is only in PHP 5.6 or later. Unfortunately getting infrastructure to update it is a headache.

Otherwise, this does actually work in some case. I really need to bludgeon them into updating...

Comment: Until then you're stuck with `session_write_close()`; same effect.

Answer (score 1):

It's PHP session blocking mechanism.

You need to call session_write_close() when you don't need session any more.
May be after this string:

```
$dataset = get_event_list($conn, $_SESSION['username']);
```

After calling session_write_close() you can't use $_SESSION.

Comment: "May be after this string:" - That would be too late ;-)